# Model relation not working

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm am trying to figure out how to make the model relation to work in **loopback**.

I already managed to make one work (with **Country** *hasMany* **CountryLanguage**), this one shows up in the Countries URL.
But When I tried to do another one it doesn't work.

Here is what I'm trying to do :

I have a *User* model and an *Event* model, and I want the *Event* model to be linked with the users that created the event, but I also want an many-to-many relationship to manage the user's subscription to an event. I already tried the hasMany and it doesnt work, well it doesn't show up in the explorer.

About the ownership relation is it just a **Event** *hasOne* **User** ?

UPDATE :

Here is my relation for the users :

```
"relations": {
    "publicEvents": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "PublicEvent",
      "foreignKey": ""
    },
    "privateEvents": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "PrivateEvent",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
```

So now the relation for the event is working as in a User can be an owner of an Event, and I also don't know if I chose the correct relation is hasMany enough in this case? (Also there are no relation declared in the event model)

But know I want also the user to be able to subscribe to an Event, I created two model for this **PublicSubscriptions** and **PrivateSubscriptions** in which I put:

```
"properties": {
    "userId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "privateEventId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
```

But I don't know it this the way to do it, I suppose these fields are not required and relation can work this out for me but I don't know which one to choose.

Comment: Can you share your common model config files with us? That will help debug the issue. These would be in: `project-root/common/models/model-name.json`

Comment: @jakerella I finally found what was the problem (name conflict with the built in model User). But stil to manage the subscription to an event do I have to create a new model? with hasManyThrough ?

Comment: What have you tried already for that relationship? Can you show us the configuration for `User` and `Event`?

Comment: @jakerella I updated the questions with some informations that might help what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating two models for Event you could have a single Event model, and two relations

> relation createdEvents : User hasMany Event
>
> relation subscribedEvents : User hasMany Event

Then, you should have some User with specific custom role ("eventCreator" for instance) for the first relation. Users under this role have more rights (like creating an event).

Standard users will only be able to subscribe. Subscriptions can thus be tracked using the second relation.

Hope this helps